# Maquina virtual no reconoce toda la RAM que le asigno

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Tengo una maquina virtual windows 7 home premium la cual tengo asignada en virtual box
8GB de RAM - > 8192MB

Si me meto dentro de la maquina virtual me aparece como que solo tengo 3,5GB..
Y la verdad que es bastante pesado con algunos programas.

Decir que en el ordenador principal donde esta instala virtual box tiene 16GB ->16384MB

La verdad que he estado mirando y no encuentro nada.

Si me meto en el administrador de tareas de la maquina virtual me aparecen total 3583MB

Gracias, si necesitais algo de informacion os la doy.

Comment: ¿Qué imagen estás usando, de 32 o 64 bits?

Comment: 32bits, gracias.

Comment: Los windows de 32 bits no soportan mas de 4Gb de ram

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un sistema de 32 bits usa registros de ese tamaño para direccionar la memoria, esto siginifica que sólo puede especificar 2<sup>32</sup> direcciones distintas, que es exactamente:

2<sup>32</sup> = 4.294.967.296 bytes = 4 Gbytes.

Pero parte de esas direcciones están reservadas para los dispositivos de entrada y salida (puertos USB, puertos PCIx, SATA, ... etc, comunicación con la placa base y su chipset...), con lo que la máxima memoria que puede usar el sistema ([sin trucos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensi%C3%B3n_de_direcci%C3%B3n_f%C3%ADsica)) es 3,5 GB.

Comment: Vale perfecto, ahora ya si que lo entiendo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: He añadido un enlace que te puede resultar interesante